# How to render a SPA created with Vue inside the editor of grapesjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, grapesjs

I'm trying to render a website created with Vue inside grapesjs' editor. But I haven't been able to successfully load it. I know it should be possible as the editor uses an iframe to load its data and if I modify the created iframe the attribute src="https://www.trinacia.com" it loads the website in the view; nevertheless, this method doesn't allow me to modify the website using grapesjs' editor, so it is not a real solution for me.

My code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="gjs">
</div>
```

JS:

```
const grapesjs = require(''grapesjs'');

const editor = grapesjs.init({
      container: '#gjs',
      allowScripts: true,
      components: '<div id="app"></div>',
      canvas: {
        scripts: [
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/js/chunk-00744b8a.c4aad12d.js',
            rel: 'prefetch',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/js/chunk-4f5311ba.cb4a3329.js',
            rel: 'prefetch',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/js/chunk-6366e45f.210d4ac5.js',
            rel: 'prefetch',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/js/chunk-658805ed.26c40976.js',
            rel: 'prefetch',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/js/compute.111be4ce.js',
            rel: 'prefetch',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/js/app.f7d0b0a9.js',
            rel: 'preload',
            as: 'script',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/js/chunk-vendors.1a362517.js',
            rel: 'preload',
            as: 'script',
          },
        ],
        styles: [
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/css/chunk-00744b8a.b37a4bad.css',
            rel: 'prefetch',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/css/chunk-658805ed.a0213277.css',
            rel: 'prefetch',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/css/chunk-658805ed.a0213277.css',
            rel: 'prefetch',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/css/app.526274ca.css',
            rel: 'preload',
            as: 'style',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/css/chunk-vendors.e2eba18d.css',
            rel: 'preload',
            as: 'style',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/css/chunk-vendors.e2eba18d.css',
            rel: 'stylesheet',
          },
          {
            src: 'https://www.trinacia.com/css/app.526274ca.css',
            rel: 'stylesheet',
          },
        ],
      },
      storageManager: false,
});
editor.render();
```

The website I'm trying to load into the editor can be found here: https://www.trinacia.com

The HTML for that website is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
      <title>Trinacia</title>
      <link href="/css/chunk-00744b8a.b37a4bad.css" rel="prefetch">
      <link href="/css/chunk-658805ed.a0213277.css" rel="prefetch">
      <link href="/css/compute.16404adf.css" rel="prefetch">
      <link href="/js/chunk-00744b8a.c4aad12d.js" rel="prefetch">
      <link href="/js/chunk-4f5311ba.cb4a3329.js" rel="prefetch">
      <link href="/js/chunk-6366e45f.210d4ac5.js" rel="prefetch">
      <link href="/js/chunk-658805ed.26c40976.js" rel="prefetch">
      <link href="/js/compute.111be4ce.js" rel="prefetch">
      <link href="/css/app.526274ca.css" rel="preload" as="style">
      <link href="/css/chunk-vendors.e2eba18d.css" rel="preload" as="style">
      <link href="/js/app.f7d0b0a9.js" rel="preload" as="script">
      <link href="/js/chunk-vendors.1a362517.js" rel="preload" as="script">
      <link href="/css/chunk-vendors.e2eba18d.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="/css/app.526274ca.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript><strong>We're sorry but Trinacia doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <script src="/js/chunk-vendors.1a362517.js"></script><script src="/js/app.f7d0b0a9.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that the injected js from the vue application modified the iframe document and breaks the grapesjs document structure, so in order to actually get the website to render I had to use the crhome selenium API at a backend service and extract all the document components after the Vue app created all the required DOM elements and inject them in the grapesjs as components.